# MSBUILD Generate xml documentation file for all projects in solution (without touching the projects)

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to create the XML documentation for all the projects in the solution even when the option its not checked in the project properties (and this is the key point).

I'm using TFS 2010 SP1 and tried with this "/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true /p:GenerateDocumentation=true" in the "MSBuild Arguments" field of my build definition. It doesn't generate anything.

I also tried with /p:DocumentationFile=foo.xml, which it does work but I assuming the file gets overridden by the last compiled project, so I tried using a variable instead but with no luck, I tried with

```
/p:DocumentationFile=$(Project).xml,
/p:DocumentationFile=$(localProject).xml
/p:DocumentationFile=$(localBuildProjectItem).xml
```

Is there a way to create the XML documentation for all the projects from within MSBUILD even though the option is not checked in the project?

PS: And yes I already see another thread similar to this but I don't want to modify the projects, that's the whole point of doing it with MSBUILD.

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? the one below does not solve the issue

Comment: Nop, as far as I know, this is the best we can get

Comment: I was thinking a possible solution, would be iterating through the sln and building the csproj separately, then DocumentationFile=.. would work, i saw this but i have never seen this type of syntax before in a build script http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e46e2500-0acc-4e0f-95aa-ed282a73d2b0/get-all-csproj-files-in-build-template-when-building-sln

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your process template (i.e.: `$/yourproject/BuildProcessTemplates/DefaultTemplate.xaml`)
2. Scroll down to find the `Compile the Project` activity.
3. Add a new variable named `DocumentationFile`, type=`String`, scope=`Compile the Project`
4. Set its default value to:

   `String.Format("{0}.XML", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(serverBuildProjectItem))`
   [image: Compile the Project]
5. Save changes and scroll down to `Run MSBuild for Project` activity.
6. In `CommandLineArguments`, set the following value:
    `String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0};DocumentationFile={1}", MSBuildArguments, DocumentationFile)`
   [image: Run MSBuild for Project]
7. Check-in the changes and build. This should generate the documentation even if it was not set by the project.

Comment: I will mark this answer because i think its the best we can get without modifying the task, it seems that in the msbuild task the project collection really is the solutions selected in the build definition and not the individual projects of each solution

Comment: this creates the xml file but it does not prevent the file from being replaced when building an sln with multiple projects

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to achieve this and finally I came up with a solution following these steps:

- Create a `Directory.Build.props` file in the solution root folder.
- Set `GenerateDocumentationFile` property to `true`.
- Set `DocumentationFile` property.

By default you would use `$(OutputPath)` and `$(AssemblyName)` properties to set the documentation file name, like this:

```xml
<DocumentationFile>$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
```

But unfortunately this does not work as `Directory.Build.props` file is processed first hence properties set in `.csproj` files are unavailable at this point.

Fortunately there is another property that gets the current project name: `$(MSBuildProjectName)`

The output path by default is the following:

- for Web projects: `bin\`
- for other projects: `bin\$(Configuration)\`, e.g. `bin\Debug\`

To decide whether a project is a web project or not I used the name of the project which ends either with `.Web` or `.WebApi`

So the complete `Directory.Build.props` file looks like this in my case:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
        <!-- The rest is omitted for clarity. -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- warning CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member -->
        <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.Web')) Or $(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.WebApi'))">
        <DocumentationFile>bin\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="!$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.Web')) And !$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('.WebApi'))">
        <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see there is also a `<NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>` property set which tells the compiler not to produce warning messages for publicly visible types where XML document is missing.

Hope it helps.